# Set emoji size to UITextField programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uitextfield, emoji

I have a UITextView set by interface builder. Depending on the user's actions, I want to display an emoji inside the textfield. This is how I do it right now (capturing in a NSString):

```
emojiSelected = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\xF0\x9F\x98\x9C"];
```

And then later on (setting the UITextField):

```
cell.emoji.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleColorEmoji" size:40.0];
cell.emoji.text = emojiSelected;
```

Now this works, except the emoji is tiny - barely visible. I have tried to change the font to make it big, but nothing changes. Note that I have set the font the same way in interface builder. If I copy paste an emoji from the web and copy it in my textfield in IB, I can change the size to whatever I want. Can we do that programmatically?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UTrnO.png

Comment: ^Works fine for me... (With `AppleColorEmoji` or `Apple Color Emoji` your error is elsewhere, please post more code.

Comment: Hi, You used a UILabel in your code that's why. I replaced my UITextView with a UILabel and it works with the same code

Answer (score 2):

Use a UILabel instead of a UITextView and it should work!

---

If you want a UITextView type section instead of a UILabel you can use a UIWebView with custom html loaded that has a `<text area>` tag and allow users to type in that. You can retrieve what is typed via javascript injection. (Side note: you can give UIWebView's transparent backgrounds)

Comment: Yup, I gave up UITextView and used UILabel, it works fine. For posterity, is it possible with a textview in any way?

Comment: @anthoprotic Not to my knowledge! Lukcy for us UILabels can be multi-line so there really is no difference once you stick a UILabel inside a UIScrollView